# What device is this?

Tags: hardware

I found this old device, but I don't know what it is.

[image: Front]

[image: Front zoom]

[image: Back]

Answer (score 4):

I think it's an impedance matching device for antenna.

If you have someone in your house in the past who was engaged in amateur radio and in addition, there is such a tool:
[image: PreStel VHF/UHF Field Strength Meter]
[image: PreStel VHF/UHF Field Strength Meter]

then it is most likely.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I don't have any other device with it, but it might be that.